# How Round robin CPU scheduling algorithm deal with I/O-bound processes?

Tags: operating-system, cpu, cpu-architecture, scheduling

I am recently taking a course called The principle of operating system, and I learned CPU scheduling. I am confused about Round robin scheduling, for I/O-bound process, for example, the process will use CPU for 2ms and does I/O for 8ms. Will scheduler still assign a quantum to this process when it is doing I/O? Also, when this process is doing I/O, will the scheduler wait for the I/O to complete even when the quantum expires or it will just start to execute next process? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You may need to clarify.  I am not sure what you mean by _"CPU for 2ms and does I/O for 8ms"_.  The CPU _only_ executes instructions, and a "process" is a sequence of instructions. A process uses the CPU the entire time it is active, there is no distinct I/O time - some of those instructions may involve I/O operations.  Further some I/O hardware may operate concurrently to the CPU or use DMA - that however is independent of the CPU scheduler.  In the end however your course tutor is who you should be asking - he/she will have the benefit of context within the course material.

Comment: In general, the scheduler only deals with *runnable* processes -- processes that are waiting for I/O will not be runnable, so will not be assigned time slices.

Comment: @ChrisDodd : your comment is probably worth posting as an answer.  Succinct and clear as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will scheduler still assign a quantum to this process when it is doing I/O?

Typically each task has a state, maybe one of:

- running, currently using CPU
- ready to run, waiting to use CPU
- blocked, waiting for something (disk IO, a mutex, a time delay, a network packet to arrive, ...)

The scheduler only cares about tasks that are running and ready to run - e.g. it might have a (circular singly linked?) list of tasks that want CPU time, and when a task blocks the task is removed from that list (and then later when whatever the task was waiting for happens and the task is unblocked, the task is put back on the list).

Traditionally; when a task is put back on the list it's put back on the end of the list, so that a task can't repeatedly block briefly to get a new time slice and hog the CPU.

This means that if there are 2 tasks and one blocks, a round robin scheduler might do "task A, task B, task A, task B" while task A is running/ready to run; then switch to "task B, task B, task B, task B" while task A is blocked; then after task A unblocks it'd go back to "task B, task A, task B, task A, ..." (starting with task B because task A was put on the end of the list and not the start of the list).

The other thing is that tasks literally can't decide to do something that would cause them to block unless they're currently running; which means that whenever a task blocks it doesn't use its whole time slice. For example, if the scheduler is giving out 1 ms time slices then a task may block after using 0.3 ms of its time slice, leaving a remainder of 0.7 ms. For this reason the scheduler needs a timer with higher precision and the length of time slices will be rounded to the precision of the timer IRQ (e.g. if the scheduler is using a timer IRQ that occurs every 0.2 ms; then that remaining 0.7 ms left after one task blocks might be rounded to 0.8 ms leaving a spare 0.1 ms due to rounding, and the next task might actually get 1.1 ms of CPU time instead of 1.0 ms of CPU time because of that "rounding to the timer's precision").

Also; when all tasks are blocked the scheduler's timer can be suppressed/disabled (and the CPUs put into a power saving state) to reduce power consumption by preventing pointless timer IRQs from waking the CPU out of a power saving state; and when only one task can run the scheduler's timer can be also be suppressed/disabled (and the task given an "effectively infinite" time slice) to prevent the overhead of pointless timer IRQs from decreasing the performance of the task.

Note 1: Almost all universities ignore reality; starting with the extremely dodgy assumption that its possible to know how long a task will use CPU time and when it will block or use IO (followed by the assumption that everything happens in nicely "aligned to time slice duration" boundaries).

Note 2: Almost all universities assume that "IO" means the initiating task is blocked; either because the disk controller does the IO while the CPU does other things, or because one or more different task/s use the CPU to do the IO while the initiating task blocks (e.g. your task calls "read()", your task is blocked and a file system task is unblocked, the file system task asks the disk controller's driver to fetch some data, the file system task is blocked and the disk controller driver's task is unblocked, then ...). This isn't strictly true in all cases (but may be true in all cases for some operating systems).

Answer (score 1):

In general time critical I/O will typically be handled by an interrupt handler rather than a round-robin scheduled process.

For example, say you have a UART with no hardware FIFO, a character arriving in its data-register, must be read before it is overwritten by the next received character.  In this case the character might be placed in a software FIFO buffer (a pipe or queue).  That buffer would need to be large enough to capture all data received while the receiving process is not running.  When the receiving process is scheduled it will receive all buffered data at once.

In other cases, I/O may use DMA operations, which occur in parallel to CPU operations. There is still often an interrupt handler involved but it would be a DMA controller interrupt rather than an interrupt from the I/O device.

Non time-critical I/O may simply be polled or asserted in a round-robin process when no precise timing is required.

If an application has a great deal of time-critical I/O and also time critical data processing. Round-robin scheduling may not be appropriate.  Real-time operating systems generally use priority based premptive scheduling, with round-robin for tasks if equal priority.

The concept that a process either uses the CPU or does I/O however makes no sense, a process runs on the CPU, whether it is performing I/O or data processing.  In fact for memory mapped I/O the CPU makes no real distinction.

Comment: Not all I/O requires the CPU the whole time.  8 ms of I/O could mean that it's blocked for that long while waiting for a rotational disk to respond to a request for a block of data, e.g. after a `read` or `stat` or `open` system call, or a hard page fault.  Or a blocking `read` on a network socket, or any number of other situations where a process could block on a syscall or page fault.  With DMA, even the actual transfer of data into kernel memory doesn't need the CPU for every byte or word, the kernel just gets an interrupt when it's done.

Comment: Anyway, *blocking on I/O* makes it sensible to talk about things this way; hopefully that's what the OP means by "8 ms of I/O".  Not just a phase of execution where the process is making multiple system calls to copy data to/from the pagecache with write/read syscalls, and only sometimes blocking for short intervals, if at all.

Comment: @PeterCordes The question is at best ambiguous.  My intention would be to improve or focus it should the OP provide clarification.   I am not clear whether your comments are a criticism, clarification or additional information, but nothing to disagree with.  You might post an answer to elaborate in these subjects

Comment: mostly was commenting as a response to your last paragraph, disagreeing with the "The concept that a process either uses the CPU or does I/O however makes no sense".  Brendan's answer puts it better, and also discussing other (over)simplifications university OS theory courses make which this question seems to be based on.

Comment: @PeterCordes : the last paragraph was really a comment on the quality of the question.  It is perhaps a statement of  opinion, but gives context to the approach I took in attempting to answer.  The question refers to a _process_ using the CPU _or_ doing I/O, but a process _runs on the CPU, and may perform I/O as part of that execution.  That is what IMO is unclear.  There are some confused concepts in the question.

Comment: @PeterCordes I in fact rather like Chris Dodd's comment, succinct and precise.  Probably an answer in its own right.